# Visual Studio private gallery auto update extensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-update, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

So I created a private extension gallery in Visual Studio and published an extension.

I wanted to create another extension which would automatically update the first one when an update is available.
I found a sample source code (https://github.com/madskristensen/ExtensionUpdater) for seeking and updating extensions automatically using the *ExtensionRepositoryService* which exposes ability to query an online Visual Studio Extensions repository.

The *ExtensionRepositoryService* comes predefined and connected to the Visual Studio Gallery once it is returned using the *Package.GetService(Type)* method the following way:

```
var repository = (IVsExtensionRepository)GetService(typeof(SVsExtensionRepository));
```

Querying the repository later is achieved using the following code:

```
var entry = _repository.CreateQuery<GalleryEntry>(false, true, "ExtensionManagerUpdate")
                        .Where(e => e.VsixID == extension.Header.Identifier)
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to utilize the same API to connect to a **private** VS gallery and query the provided extensions in the gallery?

Comment: VS 2015 automatically updates most extensions

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't need to make extensions update other extensions...

Comment: our corporate developers use vs2010 and 2013 mostly, I cannot assume they have the most updated VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a CustomGallery class which implements the IVsExtensionRepository interface

The class has one constructor that receives XML file path and parses the XML to read the private gallery atom file.
I used Lync to query the CustomGallery object easily

Comment: Could you please post\refer to your implementation of IVsExtensionRepository as I tried to search all the web to find any implementation for that interface but no way... I suffered to imitate the main extension gallery functionalities for the purpose of private extension gallery... Thanks.